# Can't add a using statement in View in universal phone app

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

We had a phone app in windows 8.0. Recently we started on migrating our app to 8.1. Found out we should use Universal apps instead of silverlight if we want certain features like background audio player. When doing so my current problem is that I can't add reference in my MainPage to some of the assemblies (Those I added after creating the project). I just took a windows phone 8.1 app (not silverlight). I dont have a windows desktop store app project or a shared project(I wont need a desktop application. Our app is only going to be for phone).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot add a reference to the project (i'll assume library), then probably the **Targets** of the Library are not correct.

Goto the Project's properties -> Library -> Targeting -> Targets

Make sure that the Library **includes** reference to `Windows Phone 8.1`

If you want a portable library you can reference in `Windows Phone 8.1`, `Windows Phone 8` and `Windows 8.1` you can set it's Targets to:

- `.Net Framework 4.5`
- `Windows Phone 8.1`
- `Windows Phone Silverlight 8`
- `Windows 8`

---

**Edit**

For the Telerik part, make sure that you are using the [Universal Library](http://www.telerik.com/download/windows-universal-ui), then just add the reference

```
xmlns:telerik="using:Telerik.UI.Xaml.Controls.Chart"
```

The XAML editor is very buggy sometimes and not giving an auto-complete isn't an indication that it will not find the assembly during compile.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. Its showing an error line when writing code but its compiling and deploying fine. I couldn't find the Targets thing you were talking about though (Can't see a library option in my properties tab)

Comment: Yeah... In my code I have multiple areas where the editor gives error but when compiling and running everything works. I really hope that in Windows 10 the XAML editor will work better.